# How to investigate scope in directive?

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have this plunker to show my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/bNha1xOrnhnyhvXtXSnX?p=preview

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [1,2,3,4];
}])

.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        arr: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
    link: function (scope) {
      var lengthOfArray = scope.arr.length;
      scope.test = 'The array length is ' + lengthOfArray;
    }
  };
});
```

In the plunker, everything works as i would like: I set the scope.arr array, and investigate it in the link. This gives me the possibility to add more things to the scope (test), and print this out. Using a template like this:

```
{{arr}} - {{test}}
```

.. i get this result:

```
[1,2,3,4] - The array length is 4
```

SO: In this example, the array is set on the controller directly above. But in my real implementation of this, the array is a json object, fetched from a server. The result is that i keep getting 'undefined' as the result. I think it might be because of the (little) delay from when the directive asks for the data, until it actually gets delivered, meanwhile the link in the directive have nothing to work with.

Any good ideas i can try out?

**Update:**

I've made this Plunker to show the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bNha1xOrnhnyhvXtXSnX?p=preview

Run it, and then in the result window, it should say something like this:

```
The array length is 5 
(content of array...)
```

Now then, if you go into script.js (or any other file), and add a linebreak at the bottom or something, Plunker will reload the page. And then, sometimes, the script will fail to read the array, and the output will only be:

```
(content of array...)
```

I've tried to add watch, but not sure if i'm doing it correctly.. as it doesn't seem to work.

Another funny thing is that more often than not, this works as it should on Plunker. But on localhost, this never works.

**Update 2**

I've managed to solve this using the $watch. Plunker updated to correct solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/bNha1xOrnhnyhvXtXSnX?p=preview

```
.directive('myDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
       contentOfList: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.counter = 0;
      scope.$watch('contentOfList', function() {
         scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
         var lengthOfArray = scope.contentOfList.categoryList[0].rows.length;
         scope.test = 'The array length is ' + lengthOfArray;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not define it first, you will likely hit an undefined error, since arr is only created after making the call. Did you try creating an empty array, and then populate it?

Something like:

```
angular.module('docsTransclusionExample', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.arr = [];
  $http.get("somedata.json").success(function(result) {
      $scope.arr = result;
  });
    }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1yt3OSdrrbdTpa6FnWT8?p=preview
Hope it helps

Comment: I've done it a little differently than your suggestion. Please see the update to my first post.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this issues
 1) You should fetch the data before controller init like during resolve function in routeprovider if you are using routing
2) You should use watch to watch for changes and set the property inside that

```
  scope.$watch('arr',function(newvalue,oldvalue){
            if(newvalue===oldvalue){return};
            scope.test=newvalue.length
          },true);
```

Comment: I've tried to add the watch inside the link in the directive, but it didn't seem to do the trick for me. Please see the update in my first post, there's a new Plunker that more clearly specify the problem i'm having.